# Zooming with mouse wheel -- is there a library that integrates with GSAP?

Tags: javascript, svg, zooming, mousewheel, gsap

I used svg-pan-zoom.js to zoom an svg via the mouse wheel.  It centers the zoom at the point of the mouse location. But I cannot get it to work with Greensock's javascript library (GSAP).  [Here is the codepen](http://codepen.io/AlmaTheYounger/pen/VeRzKN) (which does not use svg-pan-zoom.js).  Does anyone know of an svg zoom library that zooms with the mouse and integrates with GSAP?

```
document.getElementById("svg").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    //code to animate the viewbox
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollmagic integrates really well with GSAP. Here's a [demo](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html) on their website.

Also, here's a [tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/svg-scrolling-animation-triggered-scrollmagic/) from someone using an actual SVG with Scrollmagic and GSAP.